# How to color a text in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web, flutter-animation

I was trying to add color to my Overweight and Underweight with the color red. Could you help me by letting me know how can I do that?

Here is the code:

```
import 'dart:math';

class CalculatorBrain {
   CalculatorBrain({this.height, this.weight});

  final int height;
  final int weight;

  double _bmi;

  String calculateBMI() {
    _bmi = weight / pow(height / 100, 2);
    return _bmi.toStringAsFixed(1);
  }

  String getResults(){
    if (_bmi >= 25) {
      return 'Overweight';
    } else if (_bmi > 18.5) {
      return 'Normal';
    } else {
      return 'Underweight';
    }
  }

  String getInterpretation () {
    if (_bmi >= 25) {
      return 'You have a higher than normal weight. Try to exercise more.';
    } else if (_bmi > 18.5) {
      return 'You have a normal body weight. Good job!';
    } else {
      return 'You have a lower than normal body weight. You can eat a bit more.';
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Please be clear on what you want to show as red when it's overweight and underweight.

Comment: For both Overweight and Underweight I want to use color red

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can refer to below shared code and change it as per your requirement

```
Widget getTextWidget(String text){
   Color textColor;
   if(text.toLowerCase().contains("overweight") || text.toLowerCase().contains("underweight"))
       textColor=Colors.red;
   else textColor=Colors.black;

   return Text(text, 
          style:TextStyle(color: textColor));
}
```

call the `getTextWidget("your text here")` widget function in your widget tree where you want to show the text

Answer (score 1):

Strings can't have colors by itself in flutter. If you want to add a visible color you can make use of the Text widget. The text widget requires a string and then you can give it some styling too:

```js
return Text(
  getResults(),
    style: TextStyle(
      color: Colors.red,
   ),
);
```

Comment: Could you let me know how to use it in my code actually I'm getting errors if I try the following code?

Comment: Sure, can you describe the errors when the code is executed?

Comment: Actually, I have a constants page defined in my app in which I've defined all the constant values but as soon as I try to import getResultsColor code where it says to create me that when I've already done that in my brain page and it do not import it from there here is the code: const kResultTextStyle = TextStyle(
  color: getResultsColor(),
  fontSize: 22.0,
  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
);

Comment: The problem is a constant as it name suggests, is always the same and cant 
vary since the start of the code execution. Thing is, when you call a function, it is not constant, because if the function condition for exapmle the _bmi changes, the value of the constant should also do it, but it doesnt because it is a constant. So instead of using const, you can use final. Code: final kResultTextStyle = TextStyle( color: getResultsColor(), fontSize: 22.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, );

Hope it helps, and sorry for being late to answer, keep up learning flutter 

Answer (score 0):

When you declare a `Text` widget, you can declare also the `style` of it through the `TextStyle` class.

Here an example:

```
Text(
 "Hello world!",
  style: TextStyle(
    color: Colors.red,
  )
)
```

You can declare other style for text such as `fontWeight`, `textAlign` and so on. You can check all on the [docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/TextStyle-class.html)

In your case you can create another function that return the `TextStyle` or only the text color.

```
Color getResultColor(){
    if (_bmi >= 25) {
      return Colors.red;
    } else if (_bmi > 18.5) {
      return Colors.black;
    } else {
      return Colors.red;
    }
  }
```

Finally, your `Text` would be like:

```
Text(
 getResults(),
  style: TextStyle(
    color: getResultsColor(),
  )
)
```

Comment: Hey! I've updated my code could you please tell me how can I use this in my code?